# C# web-service instances

Tags: c#, web-services

I have the following class in Web-service App_Code:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class MyService : WebService
{
    private readonly MyServiceFacade myService;

    static MyService()
    {
    }

    public MyService()
    {
         myService = new MyServiceFacadeImpl();
    }
}
```

And now I have a question about how instances of this service are created.
For example, let we have the following class:

```
public class MyServiceFacadeImpl()
{
    private List<DateTime> dts;

    public MyServiceFacadeImpl()
    {
        dts.Add(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Now, 15 users connect to the server and authenticate using basicauth and what will happen?

- There will be 15 instances of MyServiceFacadeImpl with one DateTime in each dts
- There will be a single instance of MyServiceFacadeImpl with 15 DateTimes in dt

And, now, if I make this List static, what will happen?

I just need to implement a mechanism which will restrict the number of requests from a single user \ session per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And, now, if I make this List static, what will happen?

There will be 15 instances of MyServiceFacadeImpl with 15 DateTime in static instance of dts

> I just need to implement a mechanism which will restrict the number of
>   requests from a single user \ session per minute.

You can use [`Dictionary <string, DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where string stores the user name. It would be static or you can store dictionary in Application object. If you want to use Application object to store the state of user then this MSDN article [How to: Save Values in Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/94xkskdf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains it.

The above method are not safe to store the information that you do not want to loose. You would consider to store in information in persistent medium like database if you want it even the web services go down.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways you can solve this.
The easiest is to implement a singleton pattern where which has an internal dictionary to register a user to the number of times a user has made a request.

```
public sealed class UserRequests{

     private static readonly UserRequests instance = new UserRequests();
     public static UserRequests Instance { get { return instance; } }

     static UserRequests() {}
     private UserRequests() {}

    private Dictionary<Users,List<DateTime>> _userRequestList;

    private void AddRequest(User user){
        //Add request to internal collection
    }

    public bool CanUserMakeRequest(User user){
       //Call clean up method to remove old requests for this user        

       // check the requests to see if user has made too many 

       // if not call AddRequest and return true, else return false
    }
  }
```